# Changing Vue Data Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

UPDATED CODE

```
<template>
     <swiper-slide v-for="(photon,key) in $store.state.photons" :key='key'>
            <radial-gauge :value='photon.tempF'  
                 :options="photon.GaugeOptions.optionsLastTempF"></radial-gauge>
     </swiper-slide>
</template>
```

store.js

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    photons: {},
    token: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, value) {
      value.data.forEach(element => {
        state.photons[element.id].user = element.data    
        state.photons[element.id].GaugeOptions.optionsLastTempF.highlights[0].to=parseInt(element.data.tempAlert,10) 
        state.photons[element.id].GaugeOptions.optionsLastTempF.highlights[1].from=parseInt(element.data.tempAlert,10)+1 
      });
    }},
actions: {
 async getData(context) {
      let db = []
      let photon = {}
      db = await axios.get('http://13.14.13.1:3300/DB')
      db.data.forEach(item => {
        if ([Object.keys(item)[0]] in photon) {
          let dataString = (Object.values(item)[0]).split(',')
photon[Object.keys(item)[0]].GaugeOptions={}
          photon[Object.keys(item)[0]].GaugeOptions.optionsLastTempF={
            title: 'Last Temp',
            units: "°F",
            minorTicks: 10,
            majorTicks: ['0', '20', '40', '60', '80', '100', '120', '140', '160'],
            maxValue: 160,
            highlights: [{
                    "from": 0,
                    "to": 0,
                    "color": "rgba(0,255,0)"
                },
                {
                    "from":0,
                    "to": 160,
                    "color": "rgba(255,0,0)"
                },

            ],
            colorPlate: '#222',
            colorUnits: '#ccc',
            colorTitle: '#eee',
            colorNumbers: '#eee',
            width: 200,
            height: 200
          }
 context.commit('setData', photon)
    }
}
}
```

This code currently works if I go from the homepage to my chart page where this gauges are, but if i refresh the page the gauges have the right values but they aren't being properly  update.

UPDATE
so after adding a v-if to my component it now loads properly with everything. I'm now having trouble with how I would call an update function on the gauge?If i'm doing the mutation in my vuex store how would i reference my component  to call an update?

Comment: Actually your parseInt() function is missing a parameter - the radix. If you don’t set the radix (aka. base) you may get numbers in a format you don’t expect in the code. It’s suggested that you always set this parameter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Wow! I added 10 as a second parameter to all my paresInt() functions. After more fiddling I changed the optionsLastTemp to be photon.optionsLastTemp which i'm now setting in my vuex store.   setUser(state, value) {
      value.data.forEach(element => {
        state.photons[element.id].user = element.data    
        state.photons[element.id].GaugeOptions.optionsLastTempF.highlights[0].to=parseInt(element.data.tempAlert,10) 
        state.photons[element.id].GaugeOptions.optionsLastTempF.highlights[1].from=parseInt(element.data.tempAlert,10)+1 
     
      });
    },

Answer (score 0):

So, typically, Vuejs does not watch nested objects.  I'd recommend that you rework you code a bit to avoid this.  This should help: [Vue.js - How to properly watch for nested data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133894/vue-js-how-to-properly-watch-for-nested-data)

Additionally, it looks like you are trying to reference the Vuex Store object, but you are using the data method rather than the computed method, so you won't get updates on that.

Comment: This is a simplified version of my page, I have charts and the actual gauge data is reactive. When I look at the gauge component in my dev tools I see that the data has been properly set. I think it's because i'm defining it as a method.

Comment: Without seeing the whole page, it's hard to say, but typically, when using Vuex, you should respond to changes in data with the `computed()` function and then you should use mutators to change it, you should not change the observed data directly in a method.