# Vue add property to data root level and make it reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Consider below code:

```js
let myData = {
    a: 1
}

const app = new Vue({
    data: myData
});
```

As Vue docs says when we try to add a property like below, the new property isn't reactive:

```js
myData.b = 12;
console.log(app.b); // undefined
```

Vue docs suggests using `Vue.set`:

```js
Vue.set(myData, 'b', 12);
console.log(app.b); // still undefined
```

Vue docs says `Vue.set` adds a property to a reactive object!

But I want to add `b` to the data's root level. I don't know how to make `b` reactive.

Comment: I think you are looking for watchers, for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133894/vue-js-how-to-properly-watch-for-nested-data

Comment: @yuri, Thanks. The question is simple: How to create a root level property and make it reactive? `Vue.set` only works if we are adding to nested properties.

Comment: what's your exact use case?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Curiosity :))

Comment: i need to know that use case in order to suggest the best pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs clearly say you **cannot add** top [level keys](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).

> Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance.

You **must** add a key to the root level object so you can update it later.

You can either:

- create a key with a default value that you'll update. This means that you know the key before hand
- create an empty object with a generic key (for instance `dynamicProps`) and use `Vue.set` to add dynamic keys at runtime to it.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is simple: How to create a root level property and make it reactive?

The properties in `data` are only reactive if they existed when the instance was created. That means if you add a new property, like:

```
myData.b = 12;
```

Then changes to `b` will not trigger any view updates. If you know you'll need a property later, but it starts out empty or non-existent, you'll need to set some initial value. For example:

```
let myData = { a: 1, b: 0 }
// or,
let myData = { a: 1, b: null }
```

Now you can see changes to `b` are showing in the UI also:

```js
let myData = { a: 1, b: 0 }
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data: myData
})

myData.b = 12;
console.log(app.$data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp">
  <pre>{{ b }} </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew this works and it's a good alternative. But I wanted to know if it is possible to add a dynamic root-level property which name is unknown. Apparently it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find in documentation if you can add property to the root level and make it also reactive, but there is alternative solution.

```js
let myData = {
    obj: {
     a: 1
    }
}

const app = new Vue({
    data: myData,
    watch: {
      obj: {
        handler(val) {
          console.log('watching !', val)
        },
        deep: true
      }
    }
});

Vue.set(app.obj, 'b', 12)

console.log(app.$data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but you are adding a property to a nested object. As a result it is reactive just by using `Vue.set(app.obj, 'b', 12)` . No watcher needed.