# Vue watch nested property

Tags: vue.js

How can I watch a nested field on a component property in Vue?
On the data item the code is working, but when I try to watch my prop, then nothing happens.

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    dataitem: {
      nested: "",
    },
  }),
  
  props: {
    propitem: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {
          nested: "",
        };
      },
    },
  },

  watch: {
    // it is working
    "dataitem.nested": function(val) {
        console.log(val);
      }
    },

    // and it's not
    "propitem.nested": function(val) {
        console.log(val);
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133894/vue-js-how-to-properly-watch-for-nested-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use deep:true for nested data like this:

```
    watch: {
        dataitem: {
                    handler: function (val) {
                 console.log(val);  
                    },
                    deep: true
                },
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, it does the job until i do not bind the property to the component. After binding `<Test :item="{ nested: 'asd' }"></Test>` the watch stops working.

Comment: your bug in props value?
@KDani

Comment: Yes. Maybe I binding the value on the wrong way, I don't know.

Comment: before use, watch write data on other variables and write this variable in the watch.@KDani