# how to watch checkbox value in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, axios

I create some dynamic checkboxes with vue and they look like this;

```html
<li v-for="element in checklist" :key="element.id" class="block w-full p-1">
            <div v-if="element.taskId == task" class="w-full border-2 rounded-md p-4">
              <div class="float-right">
                <button @click="deleteCheck(element.id)">
                  <Trash2Icon class="px-1"/>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="flex">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="element.checked" class="w-6">
                <label for="checkbox" class="px-2">{{element.content}}</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
```

I want to watch **"element.checked"** value with watch() function in vue and I want to post it to API with using **axios**. and its looks maybe like this;

```js
watch: {
 element.checked() { // doesn't work
  axios.put('api/blabla' + element.id, // I'm not sure here, I'm just trying to compare
   checked: this.element.checked
  })
  .catch(err => {
     console.log(err)
  })
 }
}
```

I'm just looking for a method, it could be different.
the above code is just a guess
element.checked is gives an error.

btw my **checklist** looks like;

````json
"checklist": [
    {
      "content": "lorem ipsum dolor",
      "checked": true,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "content": "lorem ipsum dolor sit",
      "checked": false,
      "id": 2
    },
]```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133894/vue-js-how-to-properly-watch-for-nested-data

Comment: Don't watch the checkbox at all.  Watch the variable that controls the checkbox's state.   When working in modern SPA frameworks it's best to think of the DOM as a side-effect representation of your application's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a watch here...all you need to do is bind a `@change` event like

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="element.checked" @change="customMethod" class="w-6">
```

and in methods

```
methods: {
customMethod() {
  axios.put('api/blabla' + element.id,
   checked: this.element.checked
  })
  .catch(err => {
     console.log(err)
  })
}
```