# How to watch object in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have object with longitude and latitude?

```
data(){
  return{
  center2:{lat:0,lng:0}
}

}
```

I am trying to watch it like this but not working

```
 watch:{
    "center2.lat":function (newValue, oldValue) {
     
      this.center2.lat = newValue;
    }
    , "center2.lng":function (newValue, oldValue) {
     
      this.center2.lng = newValue;
    }
    },
```

How I could do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js - How to properly watch for nested data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133894/vue-js-how-to-properly-watch-for-nested-data)

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watching-reactive-objects

Comment: This is weird code. You watch and mutate it. It’s like recursion for mutating state.. and keep mutating forever once the value changes

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this code example.

1. Vue watch child property

   watch:{
   'item.someOtherProp'(newVal){
   //to work with changes in "myArray"
   },
   'item.prop'(newVal){
   //to work with changes in prop
   }
   }
2. Vue watch object member

   watch: {
   item: {
   handler(val){
   // do stuff
   },
   deep: true
   }
   }

Also please consider this reference.https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch. You can deeply watch objects for changes.

Comment: Instead of copying code from a duplicate question its better to flag the current question as duplicate ([if you have enough reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)).