# How to update/refresh v-date-picker if start and end dates changes?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I use V-Calendar Plugin for Vue JS (latest second version):
https://v2.vcalendar.io/.
I have the following v-date-picker in the child component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <vc-date-picker v-model="range" is-range/>
    </div>
</template>
  
<script>

export default {

    data() {
        return {
            range: {
                highlight: true,
                start: this.calendarRange.start,
                end: this.calendarRange.end,
            },
        }
    },
    props: ['calendarRange'],
}
```

The property calendarRange comes from the parent component.
What I want to do is, to refresh/rerender vc-calendar every time the values this.calendarRange.start/end change. What now happens is, that vc-date-picker displays only the initial range, i.e. takes the initial values of calendarRange property.
How to update the calendar every time the property calendarRange changes in the parent component? Thank you.

Comment: you use "v-date-picker", "vc-calendar" and "vc-date-picker" interchangeably... which is it?  what library does it come from?  you've not mentioned or tagged this key information

Comment: @yoduh sorry, you are right, I added this information above.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a deep watcher. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133894/vue-js-how-to-properly-watch-for-nested-data?rq=2