# Get Values of Nested Objects from localStorage Vue.js

Tags: json, vue.js, local-storage, v-model, nested-object

I have a vue.js application and into a component there's the data method that's returns a nested object like this:

```
obj: {
      color: {
        value: '',
      },
      shape: {
        value: '',
      },
      size: {
        value: '',
      },
}
```

Into the template a have inputs with v-models to fill these values:

```
<template>
<input
 v-model = "obj.color.value"
/>
<input
 v-model = "obj.shape.value"
/>
<input
 v-model = "obj.size.value"
/>
```

I can save this values into localStorage with the JSON.stringify method:

```
methods {

save() {
  localStorage.setItem("Itens", JSON.stringify(this.obj))
 }
}
```

and I can get this values from the localStorage with the JSON.parse:

```
created() {
 this.obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Itens"))
}
```

However, when I do this into created the input fields into template aren't filled automatically with the values of obj saved in localStorage, the fields still blank. How can I get these values saved into the localStorage e fill the fields automatically with this stored values?

Answer (score 0):

Vue does not detect changes in a nested object. You'll have to create a watcher like so:

> [Vue JS Watching deep nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45588104/18646229)

```
watch: {
    object: {
        handler(newVal, oldVal) {
            // do something with the object
        },
        deep: true,
  },
```